# How to get putty terminal to show the whole output of a command?

Tags: terminal, putty

I have got a CISCO 1900 series router. When I type a command that will give me a long output it stops showing it when the "press enter to show more" line should be written. The problem is not with the router itself, because on hyperterminal it is working as it should, but with the putty. I cannot find any options in the settings to enable longer outputs.
Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Are you connecting to the router in the same way?  (both serial line, or both telnet?).

Comment: Yes, i am connecting to the router the same way, serial and telnet both had been tried. The problem is with the putty: it doesnt show the press enter to show more line, it just stops there.

Comment: If the command simply prints everything without offering a prompt, then the router is assuming something about the terminal screensize.  If it stops in the middle, perhaps there is some difference in the way the terminals identify themselves.  (If I were debugging that, I would try connecting from some system where I could use `script` to capture the escape sequences sent to the terminal, as a first step to analyze it)

Answer (score 0):

When I run command and expect alot of output I will ussualy pipe it to the `less` program (some people use `more`)

```
command | less
```

The you can scroll through the output as you please.

Check out `man less` for more  info on how to use `less`.

---

Oh, what kind of system are you running this command on? That make invalidate this answer.

Comment: You mean my computers OS or the routers IOS? Windows 10, and i dont know the routers ios because i dont have access to it now. :)