# How To Show Complete Output on PuTTy Terminal

Tags: logging, cmd, terminal, telnet, putty

I want to run a command with a long output like say:

```
show interface description
```

which should list all the interfaces on the router. The output runs for as long as it can fill the terminal screen then requests user to press **-ENTER-** (to show another line of output) or **-SPACE-** (to show another terminal screen full).

This also happens when telnet is run on cmd.

Is there a way to have the command run completely and show all output at once?

A similar question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35073320/how-to-get-putty-terminal-to-show-the-whole-output-of-a-command) but it hasn't been very helpful.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
terminal length 0
```

To set the number of lines of output to display on the terminal screen for the current session before pausing, use the terminal length command. To revert to the default, use the no form of this command.

```
terminal length lines
terminal no length
```

**Syntax Description**

***lines:***
Number of lines to display. The range is from 0 to 511. Use 0 to not pause while displaying output.

[Read more](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/cisco-ios-in/0596008694/re825.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is it a Linux server you are connecting to?

If so you could do something similar to the answer in the question you provided in the like - `command | less` or `command | cat`

**less** would fill the terminal with output while you press enter/space to continue to the next part of text

**cat** just prints all of the output and you would have to use the scroll bar to navigate back to the top in order to read the output from the start

Hope this helps and makes sense

Comment: It is a Cisco server (Linux Based)

Comment: Someone here in the office just suggested `terminal length 0` and it worked fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I get what your trying to do, but...
Why?

I think that the way you want to accomplish this takes too long.

MY IDEA: Run the command through a .sh file and redirect it to... Let's say example.out.  Use VI or Nano to view the entire file. Use the arrow keys on your keyboard (assuming you have one and are connecting with a Windows OS) to navigate around.
 Hope this helps, brayjamin